# Wcf service client doesn't receive stream message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, autofac

I got strange problem. My mvc application doesn't want to receive stream from wcf service. By sending stream everything all right! My Client.dll.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="basicHttpStream" sendTimeout="00:05:00" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:61174/FileTransferService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpStream"
                contract="IFileTransferService" name="basicHttpStream" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client receives this message: "multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="http://tempuri.org/0";boundary="uuid:6fc3add5-b28f-4842-a944-0bb6c79d05c6+id=6";start-info="text/xml""

I'm using Autofac to create channel:

```
builder
    .Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IFileTransferService>(
        new BasicHttpBinding(),
        new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:61174/FileTransferService.svc"))).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IFileTransferService>>().CreateChannel())
    .As<IFileTransferService>()
    .UseWcfSafeRelease();
```

Comment: that is the correct header information. show the client code.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Are you sure the broblem is in client code? It is very simpe right now: `var a = _fileTransferService.DownloadFile(new ImageDownloadRequest(model.PhotoId));`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh any suggestions? I can't fix this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the decision!
The problem is in autofac configuration. I need to set the name of binding config.
The correct solution:

```
builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IFileTransferService>(
     new BasicHttpBinding("basicHttpStream"),
     new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:61174/FileTransferService.svc"))).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IFileTransferService>>().CreateChannel())
    .As<IFileTransferService>()
    .UseWcfSafeRelease();
```